# Paging is possible in Looker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, scroll-paging, data-paging, looker

I have a huge dataset in Hive. and I am using `looker` for dashboards. I need to configure and present data in `looker` for end user purposes. I cant see any documentation given by `looker` for Paging table or `scrollable` pages with paging size. For example : 10000 and number of pages 10000.

Question : Is it possible to have `pageable` tables in looker dashboard? I can't see any documentation given in official site.

Comment: Which version of `looker` you are using?

Comment: looker version 5.6

Comment: @gyan: Is there any other way we can achieve this with huge data in looker table?

Comment: Version 5.6 release has this entry `Tables in Spaces are now sortable and are paginated. This does not apply to the LookML Dashboard space.`

Comment: so I need pagination in dash board space what are other alternatives for displaying data in dashboards

Comment: One of the way could be to embed `Jquery DataTables` (https://datatables.net/) and load it using Ajax call. It would need custom code development inlooker. The DataTable is having a lot of rich features.

Answer (score -1):

I think Looker does not have any pagination for table reports but you can probably try the approach in the below link:

https://community.looker.com/lookml-5/pagination-in-looker-15168

Comment: Could you elaborate on the approach cited in the link and apply it to the question (currently the solution is link based though this could technically be classified as an answer as it states that there is no pagination at the moment - could you also find more definitive proof / documentation on that aspect as well (as I think... points to uncertainty))

Answer (score -1):

Looker has pagination because of the mentioned in charts property on how many records you have to show on your table format.

you can refer below link

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-tjqln7IqU&list=PLNfnAKZ4ZsarFIZHOkbUBPCpEXeHRgt-Y&index=19&ab_channel=UmarTazkeer

Comment: NOTE: This question is about Looker, not Looker Studio.

Comment: Also note that this could possibly be considered [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) as it's unclear why links to a specific video by a specific user and their playlist have been posted in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77272162) consecutive answers.