# Concat data using Looker

Tags: mysql, looker

Looking to take multiple rows of data and have them all listed in one column with Looker

Basic query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT booking_id, amount, type 
FROM bookings 
WHERE booking_id = 'Value'
```

It then spits out 4 columns with each one representing a different amount based on type. What I'm wanting to do is keep the booking ID in the first column and then have the different amounts and types go into their own column on the same row.  Is this possible within Looker? Our company is making the move and most of us come from a SSMS background and are very confused.

Comment: Hmm i'm not following your question. The query you provided would return only3 columns. And also are you saying for a given `booking_id` there are multiple `amount` and `type` values? If so maybe you want to pivot on `type` so then you have one row per `booking_id` and several columns representing `type` with the values being `amount`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine dimension fields in LookML using concat.  If its an integer and a string, cast the number data to a string first

```
dimension: combined_field_name {
    type: string
    sql: concat( CAST(${TABLE}.amount as string)), " " , ${TABLE}.type ) ;;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have concat 2 ways on Looker.

once a connected data source at that time have to create a field and write a formula which I have mentioned Below

> **= concat(your First(1st) field name + Your second(2nd) field name)**

and after that check the process if a shows true then your formula is right.

-> If you don't understand the concept then refer to below Link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDqdaPcafgw&ab_channel=UmarTazkeer

Also, do a 2nd way using your database Source.

there write a query and create a runtime field at that time you have the same formula apply

> **concat(your First(1st) field name + Your second(2nd) field name)**

and refresh a field on Looker Studio you do both ways.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: NOTE: This question is about Looker, not Looker Studio.

Comment: Also note that this could possibly be considered [spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) as it's unclear why links to a specific video by a specific user and their playlist has posted in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77272537) consecutive answers.